# I have a problem solving a Differential equation exact problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$\left(x+y\right)+\left(x+y^2\right)y'=0$$

What's the solution of this with steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation is exact;
$$P(x,y)=x+y,Q(x,y)=x+y^2$$ so
$$\frac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial y}=1=\frac{\partial Q(x,y)}{\partial x}$$ and we can write $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+xy+g(y)$$ to compute $$g(y)$$ we write
$$x+\frac{d g(y)}{dy}=x+y^2$$
Can you finish?
$$g(y)=\int y^2dy=\frac{y^3}{3}$$